# Insert items from MultiIndexed dataframe into regular dataframe based on time

Tags: pandas

I have this regular dataframe indexed by 'Date', called ES:

```
     Price  Day Hour    num_obs med abs_med Ret
Date                            
2006-01-03 08:30:00 1260.583333 1   8   199 1260.416667 0.166667    0.000364
2006-01-03 08:35:00 1261.291667 1   8   199 1260.697917 0.593750    0.000562
2006-01-03 08:40:00 1261.125000 1   8   199 1260.843750 0.281250    -0.000132
2006-01-03 08:45:00 1260.958333 1   8   199 1260.895833 0.062500    -0.000132
2006-01-03 08:50:00 1261.214286 1   8   199 1260.937500 0.276786    0.000203
```

I have this other dataframe indexed by the following MultiIndex. The first index goes from 0 to 23 and the second index goes from 0 to 55. In other words we have daily 5 minute increment data.

```
        5min_Ret
0   0   2.235875e-06
    5   9.814064e-07
    10  -1.453213e-06
    15  4.295757e-06
    20  5.884896e-07
    25  -1.340122e-06
    30  9.470660e-06
    35  1.178204e-06
    40  -1.111621e-05
    45  1.159005e-05
    50  6.148861e-06
    55  1.070586e-05
1   0   1.485287e-05
    5   3.018576e-06
    10  -1.513273e-05
    15  -1.105312e-05
    20  3.600874e-06
    ...
```

I want to create a column in the original dataframe, ES, that has the appropriate '5min_Ret' at each appropriate hour/5minute combo.

I've tried multiple things: looping over rows, finding some apply function. But nothing has worked so far. I feel like I'm overlooking a simple and Pythonic solution here.

The expected output creates a new column called '5min_ret' to the original dataframe in which each row corresponds to the correct hour/5minute pair from the smaller dataframe containing the 5min_ret

```
     Price  Day Hour    num_obs med abs_med Ret 5min_ret
Date                            
2006-01-03 08:30:00 1260.583333 1   8   199 1260.416667 0.166667    0.000364  xxxx
2006-01-03 08:35:00 1261.291667 1   8   199 1260.697917 0.593750    0.000562 xxxx
2006-01-03 08:40:00 1261.125000 1   8   199 1260.843750 0.281250    -0.000132 xxxx
2006-01-03 08:45:00 1260.958333 1   8   199 1260.895833 0.062500    -0.000132 xxxx
2006-01-03 08:50:00 1261.214286 1   8   199 1260.937500 0.276786    0.000203 xxxx
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: Added some expected output but its quite difficult to get the formatting right, hopefully the gist is there.

Comment: I was more interested to know those `xxxx`. What values would they have? This does not clear anything.

Comment: In place of the xxx should come the values from the 5min_ret column in the other dataframe, sorry that I did not clear this up adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way is to use `merge` on hour and minute. First create a column 'min' in `ES` from the datetimeindex such as:

```
ES['min'] = ES.index.minute
```

Now you can `merge` with your multiindex DF containing the column '5min_Ret' that I named `df_multi` such as:

```
ES = ES.merge(df_multi.reset_index(), left_on = ['hour','min'], 
                 right_on = ['level_0','level_1'], how='left')
```

Here you merge on 'hour' and 'min' from `ES` with 'level_0' and 'level_1', which are created from your multiindex of `df_multi` when you do `reset_index`, and on the value of the left df (being `ES`)

You should get a new column in `ES` named '5min_Ret' with the value you are looking for. You can drop the colum 'min' if you don't need it anymore by `ES = ES.drop('min',axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly. Was very fast on ~1 million rows. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rainymood glad is helps, and yes, `merge` is a pretty efficient method in pandas.